# Modifying motion vectors in ffmpeg H.264 decoder

Tags: vector, ffmpeg, h.264, motion, decoder

For research purposes, I am trying to modify H.264 motion vectors (MVs) for each P- and B-frame prior to motion compensation during the decoding process. I am using FFmpeg for this purpose. An example of a modification is replacing each MV with its original spatial neighbors and then using the resultant MVs for motion compensation, rather than the original ones. Please direct me appropriately.

So far, I have been able to do a simple modification of MVs in the file **/libavcodec/h264_cavlc.c**. In the function, **ff_h264_decode_mb_cavlc()**, modifying the **mx** and **my** variables, for instance, by increasing their values modifies the MVs used during decoding.

For example, as shown below, the **mx** and **my** values are increased by 50, thus lengthening the MVs used in the decoder.

```
mx += get_se_golomb(&s->gb)+50;
my += get_se_golomb(&s->gb)+50;
```

However, in this regard, I don't know how to access the neighbors of **mx** and **my** for my spatial mean analysis that I mentioned in the first paragraph. I believe that the key to doing so lies in manipulating the array, **mv_cache**.

Another experiment that I performed was in the file, **libavcodec/error_resilience.c**. Based on the **guess_mv()** function, I created a new function, **mean_mv()** that is executed in **ff_er_frame_end()** within the first if-statement. That first if-statement exits the function **ff_er_frame_end()** if one of the conditions is a zero error-count (s->error_count == 0). However, I decided to insert my **mean_mv()** function at this point so that is always executed when there is a zero error-count. This experiment somewhat yielded the results I wanted as I could start seeing artifacts in the top portions of the video but they were restricted just to the upper-right corner. I'm guessing that my inserted function is not being completed so as to meet playback deadlines or something.

Below is the modified if-statement. The only addition is my function, **mean_mv(s)**.

```
if(!s->error_recognition || s->error_count==0 || s->avctx->lowres ||
       s->avctx->hwaccel ||
       s->avctx->codec->capabilities&CODEC_CAP_HWACCEL_VDPAU ||
       s->picture_structure != PICT_FRAME || // we dont support ER of field pictures yet, though it should not crash if enabled
       s->error_count==3*s->mb_width*(s->avctx->skip_top + s->avctx->skip_bottom)) {
        //av_log(s->avctx, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "ff_er_frame_end in er.c\n"); //KG
        if(s->pict_type==AV_PICTURE_TYPE_P)
            mean_mv(s);
        return;
```

And here's the **mean_mv()** function I created based on **guess_mv()**.

```
static void mean_mv(MpegEncContext *s){
    //uint8_t fixed[s->mb_stride * s->mb_height];
    //const int mb_stride = s->mb_stride;
    const int mb_width = s->mb_width;
    const int mb_height= s->mb_height;
    int mb_x, mb_y, mot_step, mot_stride;

    //av_log(s->avctx, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "mean_mv\n"); //KG

    set_mv_strides(s, &mot_step, &mot_stride);

    for(mb_y=0; mb_y<s->mb_height; mb_y++){
        for(mb_x=0; mb_x<s->mb_width; mb_x++){
            const int mb_xy= mb_x + mb_y*s->mb_stride;
            const int mot_index= (mb_x + mb_y*mot_stride) * mot_step;
            int mv_predictor[4][2]={{0}};
            int ref[4]={0};
            int pred_count=0;
            int m, n;

            if(IS_INTRA(s->current_picture.f.mb_type[mb_xy])) continue;
            //if(!(s->error_status_table[mb_xy]&MV_ERROR)){
            //if (1){
            if(mb_x>0){
                mv_predictor[pred_count][0]= s->current_picture.f.motion_val[0][mot_index - mot_step][0];
                mv_predictor[pred_count][1]= s->current_picture.f.motion_val[0][mot_index - mot_step][1];
                ref         [pred_count]   = s->current_picture.f.ref_index[0][4*(mb_xy-1)];
                pred_count++;
            }

            if(mb_x+1<mb_width){
                mv_predictor[pred_count][0]= s->current_picture.f.motion_val[0][mot_index + mot_step][0];
                mv_predictor[pred_count][1]= s->current_picture.f.motion_val[0][mot_index + mot_step][1];
                ref         [pred_count]   = s->current_picture.f.ref_index[0][4*(mb_xy+1)];
                pred_count++;
            }

            if(mb_y>0){
                mv_predictor[pred_count][0]= s->current_picture.f.motion_val[0][mot_index - mot_stride*mot_step][0];
                mv_predictor[pred_count][1]= s->current_picture.f.motion_val[0][mot_index - mot_stride*mot_step][1];
                ref         [pred_count]   = s->current_picture.f.ref_index[0][4*(mb_xy-s->mb_stride)];
                pred_count++;
            }

            if(mb_y+1<mb_height){
                mv_predictor[pred_count][0]= s->current_picture.f.motion_val[0][mot_index + mot_stride*mot_step][0];
                mv_predictor[pred_count][1]= s->current_picture.f.motion_val[0][mot_index + mot_stride*mot_step][1];
                ref         [pred_count]   = s->current_picture.f.ref_index[0][4*(mb_xy+s->mb_stride)];
                pred_count++;
            }

            if(pred_count==0) continue;

            if(pred_count>=1){
                int sum_x=0, sum_y=0, sum_r=0;
                int k;

                for(k=0; k<pred_count; k++){
                    sum_x+= mv_predictor[k][0]; // Sum all the MVx from MVs avail. for EC
                    sum_y+= mv_predictor[k][1]; // Sum all the MVy from MVs avail. for EC
                    sum_r+= ref[k];
                    // if(k && ref[k] != ref[k-1])
                    // goto skip_mean_and_median;
                }

                mv_predictor[pred_count][0] = sum_x/k;
                mv_predictor[pred_count][1] = sum_y/k;
                ref         [pred_count]    = sum_r/k;
            }

            s->mv[0][0][0] = mv_predictor[pred_count][0];
            s->mv[0][0][1] = mv_predictor[pred_count][1];

            for(m=0; m<mot_step; m++){
                for(n=0; n<mot_step; n++){
                    s->current_picture.f.motion_val[0][mot_index + m + n * mot_stride][0] = s->mv[0][0][0];
                    s->current_picture.f.motion_val[0][mot_index + m + n * mot_stride][1] = s->mv[0][0][1];
                }
            }

            decode_mb(s, ref[pred_count]);

            //}
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate some assistance on how to go about this properly.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time i have been out of touch with FFMPEG's code internally.

However, given my experience with inside FFMPEG horrors (you would know what i mean), i would rather give you a simple pragmatic advice.

**Suggestion #1**
Best possibility is that when motion vector of each of the blocks are identified - you can create your own additional array inside FFMPEG encoder context (a.k.a `s`) which will store all of them. When your algorithm runs it will pick up the values from there.

**Suggestion #2**
Another thing i read (i am not sure if i read it right)

> the mx and my values are increased by 50

I think 50 is a very *large* motion vector. And usually, the F-value range of motion vector encoding would be prior restrictive. If you alter things by +/- 8 (or even +/- 16) might just be ok- but +50 could be so high that end result may *not* encode things properly.

*I didn't quite understood your objective about* `mean_mv()` *and what failure you expect from there.* Please re-phrase a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will look into your first suggestion. As for your second suggestion, it corresponds somewhat to my findings. When I read motion vector values (`mx` and `my`) in `h264_cavlc.c`, I get extraordinarily large values such as 500. That is highly unreasonable unless there is some scaling going one such as by your proposed factor of 50. Otherwise, I don't know why the motion vectors values are that big.

Comment: As for `mean_mv()` consider an P-frame. B-frame support will be added later. The P-frame contains macroblocks with motion vectors (MVs). Let us group those MVs in a set called `a`. Now, the work of `mean_mv()` is to produce a new motion vector set, `b`, which will replace `a` as the final set of MVs. Each MV in `b` is a modified version of the corresponding MV in `a`. One way of modifying a MV in `a` is by taking the spatial mean of the surrounding MVs in `a` and placing the result in `b`. This way, I can investigate the effectiveness of spatial mean and other techniques for error concealment.

Comment: `mean_mv()` is really a fantastic idea. This can also help guess Global motion vector (in MPEG4-v2 style). And also, given that you know the average scene motion, you can start all prediction from there  rather tan `(0,0)`.  Best of luck digging `ffmpeg`